# how to apply a constraint programmatically to UILabel such that it is 20px above from bottom of the view in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I am implementing autolayout in my app.I want the UILabel to be placed 20px from bottom of the screen by using autolayout programmatically.Please help me out where i am going wrong.With the below code UILabel is getting not displayed on applying bottom constrint.Below is my code.

```
 lblSwipe=[[UILabel alloc]init];
lblSwipe.text=@"Swipe to learn more";
lblSwipe.textColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
lblSwipe.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
lblSwipe.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
lblSwipe.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
[self.view addSubview:lblSwipe];

[lblSwipe setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

//to position UILabel in centre of the screen
NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint=[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:lblSwipe
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:self.view
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                   multiplier:1.0
                                   constant:0];

[self.view addConstraint:myConstraint];

//to apply a fixed width of 300 to UILabel
[lblSwipe addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lblSwipe
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:nil
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                  constant:300.0]];

  //to place UILabel 20px above from bottom of the screen
 [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lblSwipe
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:self.view
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                      constant:20.0]];
```

Answer (score 3):

The constant for the bottom constraint has to be -20 (because above means negative offset).